# Image reference doesn't not match output setting

Tags: image, output

I have set up my Blender output settings to 1200 x 450 pixels, and I also import my reference image which is the same dimensions 1200 x 450 pixels, but it's not the same scale as the output settings when I import it. Is there a way or setting which I can check to make it 100% accurate?

PS: The mesh seen in the viewport matches to the camera for the final output, it has been scaled accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Probably camera distance?

Comment: It's not scale, it's the camera distance as @Emir says. Moving the camera up and down (down in this case) would solve your problem. Alternatively, you can scale your reference image to match the camera borders.